# Dojo Toolkit support for future web standards

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dojo, web-standards

I have been very interested in what angular.js is doing to support web standards, like web components, html templates, object.observe(), model driver views, shadow dom, etc.

My question is, What is doing Dojo Toolkit to support those web standars? I mean, for example, implement Web Components for dijit' UI components would be very helpful for web developers.

I would like to know if there are plans to implement those web standars in the near future, and if there is documentation about those plans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plans emerging for Dojo 2.0 that takes advantage of many of these standards.

There is a [design document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1kqe3Oq7W6lg-JY_iqMl5G7SxGTD0uQ6FFIoP4KPAkUw) by some of the core team - but it is still very much a work in progress.